# Building PHP/MYSQL image gallery, Need a script where i get the category automatic

Tags: php, mysql, image, gallery, categories

So i have an image gallery ATM and i`m trying to add the function to it where the admin gets to upload the pictures adding his own cattegorie to it. But the pictures open by cattegory.

My question is. How do i get the images category automaticly?

```
<a href="categorie.php?categorie=Auto`s"><img src="img/autos.png" alt="autos" class ="cat"/></a>
            <a href="categorie.php?categorie=Meubels"><img src="img/Meubels.png" alt="meubels" class ="cat"/></a>
            <a href="categorie.php?categorie=Bedrijven"><img src="img/reno.png" alt="renovatie" class ="cat"/></a>
            <a href="categorie.php?categorie=Zadels"><img src="img/zadels.png" alt="zadels" class ="cat"/></a>
            <a href="categorie.php?categorie=Boten"><img src="img/boten.png" alt="boten" class ="cat"/></a>
            <a href="categorie.php?categorie=Overig"><img src="img/overig.png" alt="overig" class ="cat"/></a>
```

This is my code atm

Comment: Do you want the category name to be same as the name of the image?

Comment: What i got now is an image opening the category, but what i`m trying to do is giving the admin to add his own category.. And i want to show the category name automaticly.. without everytime adding a new category.

Comment: And if possible, i want the admin creating a new category, with its own image.. but i`m a real newb in PHP, its a schoolproject

Comment: What I have understood is that you will take inputs from the user to get the category name and the user has an option to either give a category name or select any category that has previously been entered. Is this what you want?

Comment: I`m so bad in making myself understandable.. My idea is, i got an image gallery, but every image is under a category, what i got now is a few categorys selectabla. But what i need is that the admin can add his own categorys (if possible with its own image). But now the image category is not added automaticly so i wrote it down myself. But i need the image category added automaticly and images under those category opened in a new page.

Comment: And yes what you said its exactly what i need. Got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including everything for uploading a file is going to take a lot of time. This could give you a start.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
if($_POST['submit']) {
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $query_insert = "INSERT INTO image_gallery (id, category, image_location) VALUES ('', '$category', 'uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']."');
    $result_insert = mysqli_query($link, $query_insert);

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}



?>

<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM image_gallery";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while($row = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($link, $result)){
        echo "<select name = 'category'>
                  <option value='".$row['category']."'>".$row['category']."</option>
              </select>";
    }
    echo "Category: <input type='text' name='category'>";
?>
Image <input type='file' name='file'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Here I have assumed that you have a database table named 'image_gallery' in your database and you have a folder called 'uploads'. Go through the following link, it will give you some idea about file uploading.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

All the best.

Comment: Let me know if it was of any help.